# Prove that Rational Sequence Topology.

Tags: general-topology

How can you prove that Rational Sequence Topology is indeed a topology?

This: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Rational_Sequence_Topology.

[image]

Comment: I don't particularly like that wiki page.  It should emphasize that for each irrational $x$ we are fixing a rational sequence converging to $x$ and defining a basis for a topology that depends on these fixed sequences.  It is then not hard to show the proposed basis is in fact a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  This is all you could meaningfully do to answer your question.

Comment: I was searching, and they also define it in the Counterexamples in topology book, I attach a photo so you can see it. @BrianMoehring

Comment: That excerpt is better.  As I mention, however, the only thing we _might_ show here is that the proposed basis is actually a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book gives the local neighbourhood bases at each point, and so defines a topology. There are standard axioms you could check.

But to any experienced topologist this also allows a direct description of the topology as (using $(q_n(x))_{n \in \Bbb N}$ as the rational sequence converging to $x \in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ as described)

$$\mathcal{T}=\{O \subseteq \Bbb R\mid \forall x \in O\setminus \Bbb Q: \exists N_x \in \Bbb N: \forall n \ge N_x: q_n(x) \in O\}$$

so essentially saying that all points of $O$ contain a local base element (as mentioned) inside $O$ (rational points are isolated so there always internal points). This is easily checked to be a topology. But e.g. local compactness and Hausdorffness are most easily checked directly using the local base sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any $S\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ as your subbase for a topology on $X$. This construction is always well-defined.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Rational_Sequence_Topology. These are the properties that the topology fulfills.

Comment: I know. But it doesn't make sense then to ask, "Why is this a topology?"

Comment: Have you gone through what it means to construct a topology using a basis?

Comment: I haven't read much about it, could you explain it to me. Because I understand that to prove that it is topology there are three properties, and I don't know how to prove them in that topology. @YonTeh

Comment: @BrianMoehring Different terminology I suppose. The Wikipedia article begins with "In mathematics, a base or basis for the topology... "
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)

Comment: I see now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused about the definition of the rational sequence topology.

It's not, "Here is a collection of subsets that seem to satisfy the three criteria for being a topology, please verify it."

It's, "Here is a collection of subsets, from which you will make more subsets, in such a way that the constructed subsets together **are guaranteed** to satisfy the three criteria for being a topology."

This is what it means to construct a topology using a subbase.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase

Comment: So here we don't have to prove the three properties for $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ with $\tau$ the rational sequence topology, given that they are generated by subbases?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase

Comment: That is correct

Comment: It's **not** about subbases but local bases, which have different criteria.